# event propagation cdk drag

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, event-propagation

How can I prevent dragging when I'm inside my `input` and I'm dragging around.
I only want the `pink-meat` to act as a `drag-handle`.

[!!! STACKBLITZ !!!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypuebw?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts)

#### html

```html
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    <input [placeholder]="movie" (click)="stopIt($event)" (mousemove)="stopIt($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### js

```ts
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

  stopIt(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

So far its not working :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prevent `mousedown` instead of `click` event:

```
(mousedown)="stopIt($event)"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypuebw-spywms?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html)**

Also for mobile devices maybe you will be looking for preventing `touchstart` event

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a directive and `cdkDropListDisabled` because I had a bunch of elements that should `stop dragging`.

## js

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[stopDragging]"
})
export class StopDragging
{   
    @Input() stopDragging: {bool: boolean};
    @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
    public disable(event: any): void
    { 
        debugger;
        this.stopDragging.bool = true
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event'])
    public enable(event: any): void
    {
        debugger;
        this.stopDragging.bool = false;
    }
}
```

## template

```
<ELEMENT ... [cdkDropListDisabled]="dragListDisabled.bool">

    <input [stopDragging]="dragListDisabled">

...
```